# Android Images not appearing until device is rotated

Tags: android, html, css

I'm designing for Mobile Web and have an image/button in a mobile site, (positioned by percentages) that shows up correctly on an iPhone (in portrait and landscape). 
However, when tried on most Android phones, the image does not show up until the phone is rotated to a landscape position, and then will show up in the correct position in portrait. It will not load in portrait mode with the button showing.

I've tried positioning, z-index and that doesn't seem to be what is causing it.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you share some code? Maybe we will find something wrong in your xml.

Comment: Post the layout XML associated with this activity and at least your activity's onCreate and onResume.

Comment: @EzekielBuchheit: He's not building an app but a website. Still, OP should post some HTML Code or URL that shows the issue.

Comment: Could you share some screenshots or code?

Comment: We really need your html to help you. I must admit I struggle to see why this has been upvoted 3 times, like its difficult to see how its a good question

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm able to comment yet so I will just post this here and a mod can move it if they want.

Many browsers interpret css differently. I would make sure that you do not have overflow:hidden or overflow:inerit which is taking the form of "hidden." It's the only thing I can think that would lead to it being invisible until the screen is widened.